# Parsing a 50 digit integer from a csv file: ParseIntError { kind: Overflow }

Tags: rust, rust-crates

What is the maximum number of digits that can be parsed as u128. I am encountering `Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })` while trying to parse 50 digit positive integer.

My error:

```
...
...
result: id 89 "40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353"      Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })
result: id 90 "44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535"      Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })
result: id 91 "41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954"      Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })
result: id 92 "81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280"      Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })
result: id 93 "82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608"      Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })
result: id 94 "22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197"      Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })
result: id 95 "77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617"      Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })
result: id 96 "72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516"      Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })
result: id 97 "20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722"      Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })
result: id 98 "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690"      Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })
...
...
```

Corresponding code for this:

```
fn read_num(a: &mut Reader<File>) -> Result<u128, Error> {
    let mut sum: u128 = 0;
    for(idx, res) in a.records().enumerate() {
        let res = res.unwrap();
        let val: StringRecord = res;
        let ii = val.get(0).unwrap().trim().parse::<u128>().unwrpa();
        println!("result: id {} {:?}\t {:?}", idx, val.get(0).unwrap(), ii);
    }; // This is formatted
    Ok(sum)
}
```

I initially thought it must be due the new line character at the end of every line, but `trim` supposed to remove that and it looks to me that it is removing, because the unparsed output doesn't seem to have anything except the `\t` formatter in the `println!`

Is the overflow due to inherent limitation or something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks @RayToal. I have just found that. Does that mean, I cannot parse a 50digit positive integer at all using Rust primitive types?

Comment: The largest u128 is 2**128-1 = 340282366920938463463374607431768211455, so you can't get 50 digits.

Comment: Any work around?

Comment: Do you need the integer values, or can you leave them as strings? There exist crates such as [num-bigint](https://github.com/rust-num/num-bigint) that can help you if you need to parse them. Disclaimer: I haven't tried it.

Comment: I need integer value. Thanks, let me try `num-bigint`.

Comment: I also found [this crate](https://rust-num.github.io/num/num/index.html) ... There is a parse example from strings on [this page](https://rust-num.github.io/num/num/struct.BigInt.html).

Comment: @RayToal Perhaps you would like to leave that as answer?

Comment: Yes good idea, thanks, just did. (I waited until I could actually find time to write working code.)

Comment: One decimal digit corresponds to log_2(10) ~ 3.32 bits, so 50 decimal digits require about 166 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest `u128` is 2**128-1 = 340282366920938463463374607431768211455, which is less than 50 digits, so you will have to use `struct num::bigint::BigInt` (from the [`num`](https://rust-num.github.io/num/num/index.html) crate).

You can parse big integers via the `FromStr` trait. Here is an example of parsing two 50-digit numbers and (super bonus fun time) multiplying them:

```
extern crate num;

use num::BigInt;
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::ops::Mul;

fn main() {
    let x = BigInt::from_str("9879878782352398572398755757923351299981243778899").unwrap();
    let y = BigInt::from_str("3234235766473868388883432903721391827312463782828").unwrap();
    println!("{}", x.mul(y));
}
```